# Does the given inclusion hold?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Conside the following field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ :
$$K= \mathbb{Q}(2^{1/25}) \ \ and \ \  L=\mathbb{Q}(8^{1/25}),$$

Is $K \subset L$ ?
Any hint would be helpful.

Comment: Can you express $\sqrt[25]{2}$ in terms of $(\sqrt[25]{2})^3$ by arithmetic operations or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

HINT

$8^{\frac{1}{25}}=2^{\frac{3}{25}}$

Comment: Thanks, i used it to prove the other inclusion, and it was in front of me all the time.